# uitableviewcell background color becomes clearcolor

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have problem with the cell background color becoming clearcolor always. I set the uiview background color to gray color, tableview background color to clear color and I did not set tableviewcell background color to clear color. But the cell background always appears grey. Can any one have any idea about this.

Thanks

[image]

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.view.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"TableBackGround.png"]];

    Acc_Details_TView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    Acc_Details_TView.rowHeight = 40;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TransCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    switch ([Acc_Details_SegCtrl selectedSegmentIndex]) {
        case 0:{
            if (cell == nil) {
                cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"TableCell"] autorelease];
                cell.backgroundColor =[UIColor clearColor];
                cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];
                cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[transcationsList objectAtIndex:([indexPath row])] valueForKey:@"Date"];
                cell.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
            }
            NSString *titleName =[[transcationsList objectAtIndex:([indexPath row])] valueForKey:@"Title"] ;
            if ([titleName length] > 19) {
                cell.textLabel.text = [titleName substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 20)];                
            }
            else{
                cell.textLabel.text = titleName;
            }

            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
            UILabel * acc_Amount = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(220, 5, 60,10)];
            acc_Amount.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
            acc_Amount.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            acc_Amount.text = [[transcationsList objectAtIndex:([indexPath row])] valueForKey:@"Amount"];
            acc_Amount.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:acc_Amount];
            UILabel * balance_Amount = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(220, 23, 60,10)];
            balance_Amount.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
            balance_Amount.text = @"$1234.50";
            balance_Amount.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            balance_Amount.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
            balance_Amount.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:balance_Amount];
            return cell;            
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your cells are not exactly transparent. Setting UITableView's backgroundColor does some crazy undocumented stuff. Best way to see this is to set it to some semi-transparent color like `[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.5 alpha:0.5]` by which you get something like this:

[image: weird table view]

To fix your problem, you will have to set cells' contentView.backgroundColor and backgroundColors of all the subviews after setting tableView's. Here is your cellForRowAtIndexPath: updated with this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TransCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    UIColor *cellBackgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    switch ([Acc_Details_SegCtrl selectedSegmentIndex]) {
        case 0:{
            if (cell == nil) {
                cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"TableCell"] autorelease];
                cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];
                cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[transcationsList objectAtIndex:([indexPath row])] valueForKey:@"Date"];
                cell.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
                cell.accessoryView.backgroundColor = cellBackgroundColor;
                cell.backgroundView.backgroundColor = cellBackgroundColor;
                cell.contentView.backgroundColor = cellBackgroundColor;
                cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = cellBackgroundColor;
                cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = cellBackgroundColor;
                UIView *backView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];
                backView.backgroundColor = cellBackgroundColor;
                cell.backgroundView = backView;
                [backView release];
            }
            NSString *titleName =[[transcationsList objectAtIndex:([indexPath row])] valueForKey:@"Title"] ;
            if ([titleName length] > 19) {
                cell.textLabel.text = [titleName substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 20)];                
            }
            else{
                cell.textLabel.text = titleName;
            }

            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
            UILabel * acc_Amount = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(220, 5, 60,10)];
            acc_Amount.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
            acc_Amount.backgroundColor = cellBackgroundColor;
            acc_Amount.text = [[transcationsList objectAtIndex:([indexPath row])] valueForKey:@"Amount"];
            acc_Amount.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:acc_Amount];
            UILabel * balance_Amount = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(220, 23, 60,10)];
            balance_Amount.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
            balance_Amount.text = @"$1234.50";
            balance_Amount.backgroundColor = cellBackgroundColor];
            balance_Amount.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
            balance_Amount.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:balance_Amount];
        }
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: When I used this code the area around the chevron still appears grey. SO I tried using  adding cell.accessoryview.background = cellBackgroundColor but it didnt still work. Any idea whats wrong. I am usign UITableViewCellStyleValue2 style.

Comment: In that case you need to add `cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = cellBackgroundColor;`. If it's still not working, could you please upload a screenshot?

Comment: After making the changes you told. I added image to the code. Please have a look at it. That is how my table cell appear.

Comment: Ah, yes, the problem is if you set one of the system accessory views, they are not set to the accessoryView property, so changing cell.accessoryView.backgroundColor has no effect. You should probably report this as a bug at https://bugreport.apple.com ... I think I know how to fix this, gimme a few minutes and I'll update my answer again.

Comment: There it is, hope it fixed all the holes now :) If you want to make it a little faster, you should probably put those 4 lines inside the `if (cell == nil) { ... }` to only alloc and set the backgoundView on newly created cells.

Comment: Nope it doesnt work. I think my luck is bad. I really appreciate your time. Thanks a lot

Comment: Ok, your cells are messing with me! Could you post the code relevant to your cells for me to try it out? Because it worked like a charm in this test project i mocked up.

Comment: I have updated my answer, it should ***really*** all be ok now :)

Comment: cell.contentView.backgroundColor did it!

Answer (score 5):

Try setting your cell's background colour in the method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

rather than in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

Comment: This fixed the issue for me in the past when I ran into this problem.

Comment: This one worked but the problem I see is this one sets the color of number of cells I specified in numberOfRowsInSection but not all the cells in the table view. So for me half of them are getting colored white and the rest appear grey.

Comment: Apple documentation **specifically** says to use this method, rather than the "cellForRowAtIndexPath".

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand your question. You set the table's background to grey, then clear, but you didn't set it as clear, and then it appears grey, which you didn't want even though you set it as grey?

```
table.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Comment: I set my uiview background color to grey and my tableview to clear color.