# Setting background image for cell using background color method not working

Tags: iphone, uitableview, background-image

I have a table view with some 'n' number of cells.My issue is with background image for cells!

I am already aware of the fact that apple documentation of [UITableViewCell](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html) specifically says:

**Note: If you want to change the background color of a cell (by setting the background color of a cell via the backgroundColor property declared by UIView) you must do it in the tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath: method of the delegate and not in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: of the data source.**

The above description can also be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5921300/uitableview-cell-background-color)

But my concern is not with changing the color of the cell,rather it is with setting the background image for a cell.As we know we can make use of background color property to set the background image i.e.:

```
if (cell == nil) 
{
   cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:kCellIdentifier] autorelease];
   cell.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc]initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"buttonbg.png"]];
}
```

But using background color for setting background image to a table view cell isn't working
and when I am trying to change the image but not color,why doesn't the above method/property work in datasource method(cell for row at index path)

Also to my surprise I found out that using an image view and setting the view as background view for cell works perfect and the same is suggested in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6969133/uitableviewcell-background-color-becomes-clearcolor/) by Mr.Ammy Worral. i.e.:

```
UIImage *cellImage = [UIImage imageNamed:kCellImage];
UIImageView *cellImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:cellImage];
[cell setBackgroundView:cellImageView];
```

But my doubt is why doesn't the background image work with background color method of cell!

Need some clarification on this!

Thanks all in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because the UITableView does some modification on the cell's appearance after you returned it from cellForRowAtIndexPath:. The solution is to subclass your cell and override the layoutSubviews method and do the customisation in there.

Comment: Thanks for the response,I got your point,but even in tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath: method,the UITableView will do modifications na,so why does the same work there and there is no affect in cellForRowAtIndexPath method

Comment: I am not asking about subclassing and the solution you gave Mr.H2CO3,I am talking about the reason you gave for why background color property doesn't work in datasource method!As you said tableView does some modifications on cell appearance,similar applies in the delegate method also na i.e. tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath: Why does the color property work here and not in data source method,I am asking about it,thanks :)

Comment: @EshwarChaitanya ah OK :) That's beause (I assume) that the modifications regarding the UI are done somewhere, and properties are not modified further afterwards.

Comment: The table needs the cell instance to modify it, since cellForRow is what creates/dequeues the instance, it can only happpen after that call.

Comment: @kra Yeah some what understandable and little confusing,if according to your perspective the table needs a cell instance to make modifications,it is done before setting cell image using cell.backgroundColor na,so it should happen there itself according to your point of view,I mean no need to write another method(delegate) to make it work ;)

Comment: @H2CO3 But we are modifying(making use of) the property in the delegate method na "tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:" ????

Comment: @EshwarChaitanya we don't, exactly beause they won't take effect.

Comment: @H2CO3 That's what I mean if it is not getting affected in cellForRowAtIndexPath(datasource) method,why does the same property(cell.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc]initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"buttonbg.png"]];) work in delegate method,because you said specifically "and properties are not modified further afterwards",please don't think I am arguing,but I am still unable to find out what's the reason behind apple designing certain things in such an awkward way :(

Comment: @EshwarChaitanya I can't explain it more clearly. Does it finally work for you or still not?

Comment: @H2CO3 Sorry if I am leading you annoyed,I know there is a solution for setting background image in a cell,I even achieved it,but I just want to know why the background color property for setting image works there(in delegate method:tableView:willDisplayCell),why not in cellForRowAtIndexPath,on the other side of coin,why adding an image view as a background view works for cell even in cellForRowAtIndexpath method,which means setting the background image via cell.backgroundColor should also work,banging my head to know the reason why??

Comment: @EshwarChaitanya Adding an image view works because the table view doesn't know there's another subview on your cell and so doesn't touch it. The willDisplayCell method is deigned to do what you want, as after invoking that method, the table view won't modify the cell. However, after invoking cellForRowAtIndexPath, modifications will be done. The overall workflow is something like this: cellForRowAtIndexPath, modifications, willDisplayCell, actually displaying the cell.

Comment: @H2CO3 +1 for making it clear,thanks for the patience and concern,have a nice day :)

Answer (score 1):

The tableview will automatically set the cell's background color to its own. And it does that AFTER -tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:, of course :)
You have two options:
1) Add a an extra view in your cell and set it's background color (pretty much what you did)
2) implement -tableView:willDisplayCellAtIndexPath: in your datasource/delegate (or something among those lines, cf apple docs for the exact names) and set the background color of the cell there manually.

Comment: Sorry Mr.kra I specifically mentioned my concern is not regarding  setting/changing the background color of cell,instead it is setting image with the help of cell's background color property,please go through my post once again and the comments I left below for Mr.H2CO3's answer,so that it would be much clear :)

Comment: I understand your post, you want to set the background color of the cell. The fact that the color is actually a pattern image isn't relevant here :) The table will set the color of the cell to its own AFTER cellForRowAtIndexPath. The reason it does it after is because it needs a cell to change a cell's background. So setting the color in cellForRow will not have effect, because the table will override that. Any call that comes after will work (i.e. willDisplayCellAtIndexPath works fine)

Comment: Yeah understood and Mr.H2CO3 made it more clear for me,any how +1 for the answer and concern,thanks :)